# monitor 4k to 29Hz

Tags: display, 4k-resolution

I purchased a Philips 276E8VJSB Monitor 27 "IPS 4K and I installed the monitor drivers and I have a resolution of 3840x2160 but only 29Hz of refresh: it is not possible to go further if I do not decrease the resolution.
I have an HP ProBook 450 G4 notebook with Intel HD Graphics 620 connected via HDMI: I tried to connect it via type C to the DisplayPort with 4K 60Hz cable but it is not detected as monitor but as billboard device.
Any ideas?

Comment: Over HDMI 1.4 Intel graphics only supports 4K @ 30Hz. https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/products/96551/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-620.html. Unless you have DisplayPort or your laptop uses a DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 converter chip then you will not get 60Hz.

Comment: I suspect your GPU is a bottleneck too. Just not powerful enough

Comment: oK, but because  connection by type C to the DisplayPort with 4K 60Hz cable is not detected as monitor but as billboard device?

Comment: @user2005016 apparently your laptop graphics is not able to work over USB C: http://www.technical-direct.com/en/typec_billboard/ your system does not support it but your monitor does. Graphics output over USB C is not a mandatory part of the spec, it is up to manufacturers to support it.

Comment: @Mokubai I contacted HP support and they told me that the type-c output also carries the video signal and that the problem should not be connected to an HP monitor, but I think it is as you say

Answer (score 3):

According to the
[Support information for Intel HD Graphics 620](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/96551/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-620.html),
the card only supports
[HDMI 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4),
defined at Wikipedia as:

> HDMI 1.4 added support for 4096 × 2160 at 24 Hz, 3840 × 2160 at 24, 25, and 30 Hz, and 1920 × 1080 at 120 Hz

As such, you have come up against the limitations of your display adapter.
To do better will require a better graphics card.